# Having trouble setting the width of the extlib dialog which is popped-up from inside a repeate control which inturn is within nested tabs (ie only)

Tags: internet-explorer, dojo, modal-dialog, xpages, xpages-extlib

I am having trouble in setting the width of the extension library dialog. This dialog is placed inside a repeate control which inturn is within nested tabs and as usual I am facing this problem only when the application is previewed in Internet Explorer. In all other browsers it works just fine. Just to add to it I am using the latest OneUI version for my application.

Comment: What's the specific problem with setting the width? Does it expand to the edge of the browser window?

Comment: No the problem is it only expands to a particular width. Even if I give the width as width:100% it still shows the dialog small in internet explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one of my applications I control the width of the dialog control by setting the following in CSS (in this example I set the width to 600px):

```
.lotusDialogBorder, .lotusDialog, .dijitDialogPaneContent {
    min-width: 600px;
}
```

Comment: WOW!!! That worked like magic thanks a ton for your suggestion, really appreciate it!!!